# Getting Sample Jenkins plugin running

Tags: java, xml, maven, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to get the sample Jenkins plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/hello-world-plugin) running. I'm using the maven plugin for Eclipse For the most part, it's working, but I'm getting an error in pom.xml saying `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration`. It's popping up on the opening parent tag, shown below. What should I be doing to fix this?

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.392</version>
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark it as permanent ignore. Its m2e (a eclipse-plugin) who telling you the parent has no clean integration into Eclipse.

Its a fear of dependency or contact, from Jenkins to M2E (to have m2e-specific code inside of jenkins). And a fear of dependencs or contact, from M2E to jenkins (to have jenkins-specific code inside of M2E).

After all, jenkins runs great without M2E, but M2E can not know this.